# Is there a known topological space homeomorphic to $(M\times M)/\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: general-topology, 4-manifolds

Is there a known topological space homeomorphic to $(M\times M)/\Bbb Z_2$ where $M$ denotes the Mobius strip and $\Bbb Z_2$ act by permutation?

Comment: And how does $\Bbb Z_2$ act?

Comment: by permutation.